# Has the Interpretation of the scope of the site become too narrow?

Tags: discussion, questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223334/a-fear-of-starting-to-implement-an-oop-program) (not mine) was closed very rapidly as "Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the scope defined in the FAQ." Closing this question seems to depend on a very narrow interpretation of what constitutes programming or software development - ie if it does not contain code it is not within scope. I have recently had one of my questions closed on similar grounds, but did not pursue it further since my view of that question was obviously going to be biased. Here the OP has a real problem, and is seeking advice on that problem. It does offer the opportunity to create a valuable answer that fulfils SO's original aim to improve the internet. It is true that is is more discursive than a "how to twiddle the left hand frucback in functional language scraped" but that does not (IMHO) make it an invalid question. It does seem to me that current votes to close questions are both being very quick off the mark, and as I said for this question, taking an unduly narrow interpretation of what is on or off topic.

If such questions are considered out of scope, I do think this should be considered for migration rather than closure. If there are questions of this nature what is the best way to get them answered within the Stack Overflow family of sites.

Comment: It's a whiteboard type of question, so belonging more on Programmers SE than on SO.

Comment: Looks like the question may find a better home on `Programmers`. Writers block is most certainly off-topic on Stack Overflow though.

Comment: In regards to migration - 4 out of 5 closers need to agree on the site to migrate to (and `Programmers` is off the list). If moderators are involved the ones on the receiving site need to agree that it belongs.

Comment: Its not a question. Just somebody pouring out their worries and was rightly closed imho.

Comment: @vascowhite I don't see it as "Just somebody...". Certainly there was a substantial amount of this but within this I saw a real question. In addition I saw the OP asking for sources of guidance on his real question.

Comment: "Where do I start?" isn't exactly a practical, answerable question about a specific programming problem you have encountered.

Comment: Maybe I missed it. What's the question?

Comment: @vascowhite - The question - how to determine with a new approach or technique, when a phase of that approach is sufficiently complete to move on.

Comment: Maybe. I saw it more like "I'm scared to commit, can somebody hold my hand", but I'm naturally un-sympathetic :)

Comment: @ChrisWalton: "but within this I saw a real question"- even if the question were on topic for the site (I wouldn't say it was), a real question shouldn't be contained "within" an open-ended monologue. In cases where there's a good question within a worse one, it's a good idea to close it so that it can be edited into a concise form and reopened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I look at this and ask myself, "What is this person actually *asking*?"  I don't really see any sort of question that could be answered reasonably; it's a question asking an open-ended question.

This part in particular sets off my NARQ flag:

> Well long story short, I do not really know when to start coding. As
>   mentioned I already did a lot of research and derived a class
>   structure from the avaliable data and requirements. Still I am somehow
>   afraid to start implementing or to be precise I do not know where to
>   start -

It's just *too open ended* for anyone to reasonably answer.

Now, I wouldn't have closed it as off topic, but this definitely doesn't look like a real question.

Comment: This is fair enough, and is an answer to my concern about scoping being too narrowly defined.